# Receiving Hex data from terminal using UART interference

Tags: hex, stm32, uart

I want to receive hex data from terminal like 0x66, 0x55, 0x44, 0x23, 0x11, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc. Normally we can receive messages in string over UART. But I want to receive hex data instead of character or string from terminal. I am using stm32cubemx HAL library.

Can anyone give me a solution on how I can implement this?

Comment: Sprintf() should be able to help you

Comment: There is nothing like "hex data".  It will be quite difficult to enter 0xee character code in terminal.

Comment: *"Normally we can receive messages in string over UART"* -- You are confusing character codes and the binary values used for those codes. A UART transfers 5 to 9 bits of data per frame. A frame of 8 data bits (for a byte) is most common. The value of each frame can be expressed as a binary, octal, decimal, or hexadecimal number. Or the value can be treated as a character code, e.g. ASCII, and then displayed as such by a terminal emulation programs. So what do you want to do with the received data?

Comment: i need to store the recieved data in a buffer and then that buffer will be sent as CAN_TX message. and i am not allowed to use the terminal emulation program to display the data as hex. rather i have to give hex data as input thats the problem. i hope you guys understand my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally i was able to find out the solutions. the actual task was to to receive hex data from terminal like 0x66, 0x55, 0x44, 0x23, 0x11, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc via UART. After receiving the hex values i need to trnsmit these value through the CAN controller. So, there are basically two main  tasks.

1. Recieving the hex values from terminal
2. store the hex values and send them through CAN bus.

I had problem with the first task actually. To solve the problem first i have splitt the strings in hex strings where each string contains only one hex value. If the string is something like "12 34 aa bb cc 33 77 86". The tokens will be like "12" "34" "aa" "bb" "cc" "33" "77" "86". To do this i used strtok() function. Then store that tokens and use another function strtol() to convert it for hex representation.
When this was done correctly then simply sent the values in CAN transmit function.

```
    void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) // Callback-Funktion für Empfangs interrupt
{
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2,&recvd_data,1);        //  Empfangs interrupt funktion

     if(recvd_data == '\r')                         //   wenn "Enter" gedrückt wird, ist der Empfang abgeschlossen
         {
             reception_complete = TRUE;

                    char *args[15];
                    int i =0; int j=0;
                    char *token = strtok(data_buffer, " \t\n");
                    while (token != NULL) {
                        args[i++] = token;
                        token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
                    }
                    //to print the array
                    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                        printf("%s\r\n", args[j]);
                    }


             int  hexbase0=(int) strtol (args[0],NULL,16);
             int  hexbase1=(int) strtol (args[1],NULL,16);
             int  hexbase2=(int) strtol (args[2],NULL,16);
             int  hexbase3=(int) strtol (args[3],NULL,16);
             int  hexbase4=(int) strtol (args[4],NULL,16);
             int  hexbase5=(int) strtol (args[5],NULL,16);
             int  hexbase6=(int) strtol (args[6],NULL,16);
             int  hexbase7=(int) strtol (args[7],NULL,16);
             int  hexbase8=(int) strtol (args[8],NULL,16);
             //printf("%x\r\n",hexbase);


             //asciitobinary(data_buffer);
             TxData[0] = hexbase1;
             TxData[1] = hexbase2;
             TxData[2] = hexbase3;
             TxData[3] = hexbase4 ;
             TxData[4] = hexbase5;
             TxData[5] = hexbase6;
             TxData[6] = hexbase7;
             TxData[7] = hexbase8;



             TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
             TxHeader.StdId = hexbase0;
             TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
             TxHeader.DLC = 8;

              if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &TxHeader, (uint8_t*)TxData, &TxMailbox) != HAL_OK)
                         {
                             Error_Handler ();
                         }

             //HAL_UART_Transmit(huart,data_buffer,count,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
             data_buffer[count++]='\r';

             for(count=10; count>0; count--)                        //buffer leer machen
              {
                 data_buffer[count]=0;
              }
         }
         else
         {
             data_buffer[count++] = recvd_data;
         }

}
```